# Who were the parents of William H. Clements, husband of Lulie Ida Strong?

Tags: birth-records, tennessee

I have hit a dead end with [William H. Clements](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Clements-2258) (b.c. 1829), husband of [Loula/Lulie Ida Strong](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Strong-2562) and father of [Lyman Jairus Clements](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Clements-2254).  Thanks to his distinctively named wife, I was able to find the following in government records:

- He married Lulie Ida Strong on 1 Jan 1863 in Avoyelles, Lousiana, or [Warren County, Mississippi](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:V28L-XLC).
- The [1870 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MD87-33C) reports William Clemens [sic] living in Memphis Ward 8, Shelby, Tennessee, with his wife Ida Clemens (who was born in Louisiana about 1839) and son Lyman Clemens (who was born in Louisiana about 1866).  William's birth location is Tennessee and approximate birth year is 1829.
- His wife is listed as a widow in Vicksburg, Warren, Mississippi, in the [1880 US Federal census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M4P4-6ZX), implying he died between 1870 and 1880.

I have not been able to find any further information, even unsourced, through Ancestry.com, FamilySearch.org, and Find A Grave.  There is no shortage of information about his son Lyman Jairus Clements.  (The only anomaly is that Lyman Jairus' birthplace is listed as Mississippi in later censuses.)

Can anyone point me to further information?

Comment: What sources have you seen besides the 1870 and 1880 Census schedules?

Comment: What's your source for the Louisiana Marriage? Could this index entry from Mississippi be the right couple? https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:V28L-XLC

Comment: @JanMurphy Thanks for the Mississippi record, which looks like a match. Thanks too for the edit.  All the information I have is at http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Clements-2258

Comment: It's helpful if you can include a list of the source records being cited here in your question, especially since WikiTree is collaborative.  Someone reading this question a year later who goes to WikiTree will see the state of research on the person which is current at that time.  They won't be able to see what your picture of this couple was like at the time you asked the question.

Comment: The problem with both of those marriages -- the one that put them in Louisiana and the Mississippi one -- is that they are both derived records (transcriptions or indexes), right?  So in order to say which hypothesis is correct the researcher needs to hunt down the actual record to find out what it says.  They may list the parents, but that in itself isn't proof, because original records can lie.

Comment: @JanMurphy I know that there's no such thing as proof in genealogy (except possibly for DNA), but some records are likelier to be correct than others.  I'll add source links to the question, although I think up-to-date information is likelier to be of interest to later readers.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you not link to WikiTree at all. I'm saying that when you only link to WikiTree, then people won't be able to see *quickly* what you have already looked at when you wrote the question.  With any online system, the readers who already know it can find the information, but readers who are not familiar with the site have to learn how to read it before they can answer you.